# How to Set date and time in datetime field in sqlserver using java prepared statement

Tags: java, sql-server, prepared-statement

I am receiving time in milliseconds and I would like to convert that into date and time format and store that value in datetime column in **sqlserver**.

Following is the code which is working and converting milliseconds to date and time but it is unable to set the date and time value in database column.

```
    String datetime = 1488288835716
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTimeInMillis(Long.parseLong(datetime));
    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss");
    String datestring= formatter.format(calendar.getTime());
    UpdateStatement.setString(1,datestring)
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem?

Comment: @GiorgosAltanis: Provided clarification on whats not working

Comment: Which is the specific type of the column with the date-time information?

Comment: @Sandro I suppose `datetime`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to convert the given milliseconds into any textual representation. In fact most databases store time / datetime values in milliseconds anyway.

Instead, use [`java.sql.Timestamp`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html?java/sql/Timestamp.html) like this:

```
long timeInMillis = 1488288835716;
Timestamp time = new Timestamp(timeInMillis);
updateStatement.setTimestamp(1, time);
```

Comment: The application on which I have added the java code, it is not identifying the timestamp method. Any other way I can implement?

Comment: @user3384231 The method `setTimestamp(int parameterIndex, Timestamp x)` is part of the `PreparedStatement` interface. Hence, there is no way the application cannot support it. Or does it throw an `UnsupportedOperationException`?

Comment: @user3384231 According to the [Microsoft Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/using-basic-data-types) it is supported.

Comment: I have added java code in an application that has groovy engine and when its compiling it giving me the error: Could not find matching constructor for: java.sql.Timestamp(null): 
javax.script.ScriptException: groovy.lang.GroovyRuntimeException: Could not find matching constructor for: java.sql.Timestamp(null)

Comment: UpdateStatement.setTimestamp(1, new Timestamp(calendar.setTimeInMillis(timeInMillis))); This is what I had in the code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136879/discussion-between-izruo-and-user3384231).

Comment: If I do like you specified then Code doesn't gets compiled and it says "unable to resolve class TimeStamp" even though in my import statement I have import.java.sql.*

Comment: @user3384231 It's `Timestamp`, not `TimeStamp` - corrected my typo - sorry for that.

Comment: U don't need to be sorry...I can just say Thank you to you. Thanks a ton. it solved the issue. I will do couple of tests more just to see if any more issues.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this, to overcome possible issues with locale, culture and so on?

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");
```

I am not proficient in Java, but this can be a problem with SQL Server, so I always put date strings in this format before writing to the database.